# Induced height imbalance in AVL tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

If a node is inserted in an AVL tree, it might happen that one of the nodes in the path to the new_node would lose height balance. But my question is if that node is fixed, can other nodes above it (the ancestors till the root) would still retain height imbalance (in case they lost the balance earlier).

I have done some paper work and could observe that such a scenario is not possible. Once height imbalance is fixed at a node, all its ancestors should be fixed automatically (if they were affected).

Answer (score 0):

The imbalance can be fixed locally; in total there are four cases that need to be considered. More precisely, it is two cases (single rotation and double rotation) with the other two ones being the mirrored versions of them; the operations are decribed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Rebalancing). There is no need to follow the path to the root and rebalance every node on this path. In total, the rebalancing can be done in constant time.